# Airflow Dependencies Blocking Task From Getting Scheduled

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an airflow instance that had been running with no problem for 2 months until Sunday. There was a blackout in a system on which my airflow tasks depend and some tasks where queued for 2 days. After that we decided it was better to mark all the tasks for that day as failed and just lose that data.

Nevertheless, now all the new tasks get trigger at the proper time but they are never being set to any state (neither queued nor running). I check the logs and I see this output:

> Dependencies Blocking Task From Getting Scheduled
>
> All dependencies are met but the task instance is not running. In most cases this just means that the task will probably be scheduled soon unless:
>
> - The scheduler is down or under heavy load
> - The following configuration values may be limiting the number of queueable processes: parallelism, dag_concurrency, max_active_dag_runs_per_dag, non_pooled_task_slot_count
> - This task instance already ran and had its state changed manually (e.g. cleared in the UI)

I get the impression the 3rd topic is the reason why it is not working. 
The scheduler and the webserver were working, however I restarted the scheduler and still I am having the same outcome. I also deleted the data in mysql database for one job and it is still not running.

I also saw a couple of post that said it is not running because the `depens_on_past` was set to true and if the previous runs failed, the next one will never be executed. I also checked it and it is not my case.

Any input would be really apreciated.
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: were you able to find out the issue ?? I am facing the same issue but not able to get the solution.

Comment: Maria,  were you able to find out the issue ?? I am facing the same issue but not able to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging a similar issue i found this setting: AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__MAX_DAGRUNS_PER_LOOP_TO_SCHEDULE (or http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/configurations-ref.html#max-dagruns-per-loop-to-schedule), checking the airflow code it seems that the scheduler queries for dagruns to examine (consider to run ti's for), this query is limited to that number of rows (or 20 by default). So if you have >20 dagruns that are in some way blocked (in our case because ti's were on up-for-retry), then it won't consider other dagruns even though these could run fine.